# Spring Directory Listener

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, listener

I'm creating a web application that uses **Apache Tomcat (Latest)**, **Spring 3**, **Struts2** and **Hibernate**. I need to have a listener that observes a directory for any new XML files that appear. While the web application is deployed onto Tomcat and running it should keep doing this.

1. What method is recommended when doing something like this, using these frameworks?
2. Are there any examples that I can look at to assist with the beginning stages?

Comment: You can try it with JDK 7.  It's got a new watcher class.  http://e-blog-java.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-watch-file-system-for-changes-in.html

Comment: Accept Dangling Piyush's answer.  It's identical to mine; s/he can use the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try jdk7 [WatchService](https://dzone.com/articles/how-watch-file-system-changes). I have already done it a project which has a similar structure to the one you have. Otherwise you could try to use [`FileAlterationListner`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationObserver.html) from `org.apache.commons.io`. I would rather go for jdk7 as it worked perfectly.

Comment: http://e-blog-java.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-watch-file-system-for-changes-in.html

Comment: what about listing on directories of server?

Answer (score 0):

i have used [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) in one of the project, it worked like charmed, if switching to JDK 7 is not possible.